# Android 10: how to check if a file path received is that of one within app-specific directory (getExternalFilesDir)

Tags: android-10.0

We need to check if uri of a file received in a common utility belongs to one that is stored within any sub-folder under app's base folder. Comparing the paths does not seem to be the right approach.

```
String basePath = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
System.out.println(basePath);
//Gives this output
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename>/files/

//Created a sub-directory, localfiles and placed test.jpg in that

//When uri of test.jpg is received and path is checked
File testFile = new File(uri.getPath());
System.out.println(testFile.getAbsolutePath());
//Output is as below
/document/primary:Android/data/<packagename>/files/localfiles/test.jpg
```

I know that test.jpg is stored within one of the sub-folders of base path returned by getExternalFilesDir but how do I confirm that programmatically ?

```
**Base path**: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename>/files/
**test.jpg path**: /document/primary:Android/data/<packagename>/files/localfiles/test.jpg
```

Appreciate your help in solving this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I confirm that programmatically ?

You don't. There is no requirement for a `Uri` that you get from the system or anywhere else to have identifying elements pointing out where the `Uri` points on the filesystem. After all, a `Uri` does not have to point to a filesystem item at all.